# React Input Value

Tags: reactjs, input

I want to clear input value (react-search-box) on focus. Value of input is `this.state.inputValue`, there is a function `clearInput2` which changes state of `this.state.inputValue` and it is definitely changed, but on screen I still see not updated value of input. I'm using react-search-box.
How can this be achieved?

```
  clearInput2(){
    this.setState({ inputValue: ""},()=>{console.log(this.state.inputValue)});
  }
```

react-search-box component

```
       <ReactSearchBox 
        placeholder="Miasto, ulica"
        value={this.state.inputValue}
        data={this.state.data}
        onSelect={this.toMap}
        onClick={this.clearInput}
        onFocus={this.clearInput2}
        
      />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      <ReactSearchBox 
        placeholder="Miasto, ulica"
        value={this.state.inputValue}
        data={this.state.data}
        onSelect={this.toMap}
        onClick={this.clearInput}
        onFocus={() => {
          document.getElementsByClassName("jwfbbd")[0].value = ""
        }}
        
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     <ReactSearchBox
          placeholder="Miasto, ulica"
        value={this.state.inputValue}
        data={this.state.data}
        onSelect={this.toMap}
        onClick={this.clearInput}
        onFocus={() => {
        this.setState({ inputValue: ""},()=>{console.log(this.state.inputValue)})
          }}
          onChange={value => console.log(value)}
        />
```